# Not detecting collision between boundary frame and SKNode in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Here is my code in my `GameScene`. I have a simple sprite which falls down under gravity and bounces of the edges of the screen and a particle emitter. All I need is that I should be able to detect collisions between the `SKNode` and the physicsbody i.e. the frame.

**Code Used**

```
#import "GameScene.h"
@interface GameScene () <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
@property (strong) UITouch *rightTouch;
@property (strong) UITouch *leftTouch;
@property (strong) SKNode *spinnyNode;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int count;
@end
@implementation GameScene {
}
    static const uint32_t birdCategory = 1 << 0;
    static const uint32_t worldCategory = 1 << 1;
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:134/255.0 green:50/255.0 blue:148/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = worldCategory;
    NSString *burstPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fire" ofType:@"sks"];
    SKEmitterNode *burstNode = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:burstPath];
    burstNode.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [self addChild:burstNode];
    self.spinnyNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"ball"];
    self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.angularVelocity = 10.0;
    self.spinnyNode.hidden = YES;
    self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = birdCategory;
    self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0x0;
//    self.spinnyNode = ball;
    SKNode *leftPaddle = [self childNodeWithName:@"bottom"];
    leftPaddle.physicsBody.angularVelocity = 10.0;
}
- (void)touchDownAtPoint:(CGPoint)pos {
    self.count = self.count+1;
    CGPoint p = pos;
    NSLog(@"/n %f %f %f %f", p.x, p.y, self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width);
    if (self.count == 1)
    {
        self.spinnyNode.position = p;
        self.spinnyNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:40];
        self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(203, 10);
        self.spinnyNode.hidden = NO;
        self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.restitution = 0.8;
        self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
        self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.3;
        self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.friction = 0.1;
        self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.angularVelocity = -100.0;
    }
}
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    NSLog(@"contact detected");
    NSString *nameA = contact.bodyA.node.name;
    NSString *nameB = contact.bodyB.node.name;
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody;
    SKPhysicsBody *secondBody;   
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }
    //Your first body is the block, secondbody is the player.
    //Implement relevant code here.

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *t in touches) {[self touchDownAtPoint:[t locationInNode:self]];
}
}
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
@end
```

This is my first time working with `SpriteKit`. So please be patient and help me out.

Comment: In didMove(toView:) create a physics body of a spinny node, then set it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the callback to didBeginContact when they touch you will need to set the contact bit mask like this:

```
self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = worldCategory;
```

currently you are setting it to 0x0 which means not to report any contacts to the delegate. You also need to set the delegate on the scene:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

**UPDATE**

You also need to put the lines:

```
self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = worldCategory;
self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = birdCategory;
```

into the touchDownAtPoint method *after* you create the physicsBody with:

```
self.spinnyNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:40];
```

otherwise they will be reset when you create the physicsBody.

Comment: Hey Simon thanks for your time but I made the changes as you suggested but it is still not working i.e. detecting collisions.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure I understand, which nodes do you need to detect the collisions between? The code I gave should work if the spinnyNode hits the frame. For other nodes you need to make sure that each one has a physicsBody, each one has a categoryBitMask, and the contactTestBitMask of each one is set to the categoryBitMask of the other.

Comment: Actually, just seen another thing, you need to move the lines: self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = birdCategory; and self.spinnyNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = worldCategory; after you create the physicsBody, I will update my answer